# PowerShell reading a filtered list of SQL Server tables

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I’m reading a list of SQL Server tables into a PowerShell array, which I’ll then loop through.  The tables I’m interested in all have the name like %PickList%.   How can I filter for that string?

Here’s what I have. Filtering for an exact match of a table name works ok, but how can I expand the search to get all such tables?

```
clear-host
Set-location SQLserver:\sql\...-CONRAD...\default\databases\PT2\tables

$a = Get-ChildItem | Where {$_.Name -eq "santitzie_PickList_Ctry_FirstName"} # ok

# Get-ChildItem | Where {$_.Schema -eq "pt2"} # ok
# Get-ChildItem | Where {$_.Name -eq "santitzie_PickList_Ctry_FirstName"}  # ok
# Get-ChildItem | Where {$_.Name -like "%PickList%"} # no
# Get-ChildItem | Where {$_.Name -eq "%Pick%"} # no

foreach ($item in $a) {Write-Host $item} # ok
```

Answer (score 4):

`-like *PickList*` would work, or you could fall back to regular .NET string comparison methods and do `$name.Contains('PickList')`.

`Contains` is case-sensitive whereas `-like` is not.

For future reference, topics like this are [easily Googleable](https://www.google.com/search?q=powershell%20like%20operator&oq=powershell%20like%20operator&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l5.2439j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).